# Batch File, search all files in folder, then sort

Tags: batch-file, find

I've done some small batch files before, but never any that required file names being read in a folder.

I need a batch file that can sort a folder for me.

I need it to look into a folder, search each text file, if it contains a "string", then move it into an accepted folder, if not, move it into a rejected folder.

Any ideas how to tackle this?

I have used something as follows for finding text before.

```
find /c "string" file
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto
```

I don't know how to make it search each file in a folder, and those file names change on a daily basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your problem statement you said all of these files are `.txt` files. So I would recommend using a `for loop` to loop through each of the `.txt` files in the directory, and then use `findstr` to search for the intended string. The code I posted below will work in such a manner. Essentially it changes the directory to the desktop (or wherever your files are located), then loops through each `.txt` files and searches for the string. The `findstr` output is redirected to `nul` (for faster processing) and if this is successful, the `.txt` file is moved to `C:\Users\Desktop\SuccessFolder`, otherwise this file is placed in `C:\Users\Desktop\FailureFolder`. (Keep in mind the search `"string"`, original location, and 2 folder locations still need to be set) I believe this code should work for what you are trying to accomplish. Let me know if any changes need to be made to the code =]

```
@Echo off
cd /D C:\Users\Desktop
FOR %%a in (*.txt) do (
findstr /C:"string" "%%a" >nul && move "%%a" "C:\Users\Desktop\SuccessFolder" || move "%%a" "C:\Users\Desktop\FailureFolder")
```

Comment: +1; But each %%a in DO() clause should be enclosed in quotes. Also will have to use FINDSTR /C option if "string" contains spaces.

Comment: @dbenham I made changes in my original answer to reflect the points you addressed. (By the way, I hope you realized I used the string output to nul (with %% and ||) which I learned from you, thanks.)

Comment: You almost had it correct. I fixed the format of the /C option - `/C:"string"`.

Comment: Thanks for you help!  I ended up using: "FOR %%a in (*.xml) do (
findstr /i ".*e202.* .*l202.* .*e203.* .*e204.* .*e201.*" %%a >nul && move %%a "C:\XMLImport" >> C:\copyxml\log.txt || move %%a "c:\copyxml\rejected" >> C:\copyxml\log.txt)  This allowed me to move every xml file containing e202, or e203, or e204 or e201 and place it in the xmlimport folder, the remaining files get put in the rejected folder.   Output also goes to a log file, though not very helpful as it doesn't show what file got moved where.